# Clipping rectangle not resizing in responsive chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It has to be pretty simple, but I can't get it to work. It's a simple responsive chart. I created a clipping rectangle so the value outside of my domains would disappear, but i could not get it to resize with the rest of the elements in the window. Could someone take a look? Here's a link to a plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/eQ4HgxQC49CZIPVBXjQX
Thanks a million!

```
 svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `resize` function add this line to update the width and height in the clip rect.

```
svg.select("#clip rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ddb0C55Zs2IvhUSB0Un6?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Cyril! Working great!